# Best way of calling another custom function in PHP

Tags: php, function, time, eval

I have a web store in PHP + MySQL. I have used a custom micro-CMS which allows products and its details (price, description, units available, etc.). The function that calculates the prices, directly from database and applying different rules is `get_price_of_product( $id_product )`, which let's say exists in `includes/functions.php`.

Now if I want to customize the micro-CMS for different customers and don't want to change the core code, I would still use the function but I need some way of calling a custom-made function, different for any different customer: `CUSTOM_ID_get_price_of_product`, which lives in `includes/functions-CUSTOM_ID.php`.  ( Each different domain will use a different installation, with only that file being different in each installation ).

I had thought of checking `function_exists` in `get_price_of_product`, and accordingly, return the correct value, but I am not sure if there is a penalty on processing time, memory or otherwise.

I understand that other options, as storing the function name in the database and `eval()`'ing the function could be potentially dangerous (security breach). Other options ?

Comment: Use a configuration file where you plug in the different functions. Your "framework" would define a `set_get_price_of_product_function` that accepts the actual function as a parameter, then based on a configuration file you initialize everything. When you need to call it you'd call `get_get_price_of_product_function` and call the returned function.

Comment: `function_exists()` won't give you any problems. Sure, it is an extra call but it's not even worth mentioning when it comes to cpu/memory. What ever you do.. do not add functions in your DB and use `eval()`... that is very very bad. Keep data in the database and code on the server.

Comment: The whole concept of functions is, to help you write a code and reuse it, so you don't have to write the same thing over and over. If you have want to customize the function per client, then that is what the parameters are for, create a unique function for each client is unspeakable mistake.

Comment: Ok, so I can use `call_user_func_array` for the last call of the function, whose name will be stored in a params.php file outside of the public html directory? Right? I have tried and seems to work fine.